# PropertyAnimation on x changes y value

Tags: qt, qml, qtquick2

Consider the following Qt QML code:

```
import QtQuick 2.7
import QtQuick.Window 2.2
import QtQuick.Controls 2.0

ApplicationWindow {
    id: mainWindow
    visible: true
    width: Screen.width / 5
    height: Screen.height

    x: 0
    y: 0

    PropertyAnimation on x {
        duration: 1000
        from: Screen.width
        to: Screen.width - mainWindow.width
    }

    Text {
        text: mainWindow.y
    }
}
```

It is supposed to create the main window of the application and to show it moving out from the right side of the screen, much like Windows 8 right side panel appears on mouse hover.

However, when I run this code, the window is not attached to the top of the screen, i.e. the y value of the window is not 0.

I have added the Text object for debugging purposes: if I comment out the PropertyAnimation block, 52 is displayed and window sticks to the top of the screen. If I uncomment the PropertyAnimation block, 62 is displayed and there is a space between the window and the top of the screen.

Despite the counterintuitive change of the y value, the animation works properly.

I have tried to setting y: 0 after animation completes or adding PropertyAnimation on y from 0 to 0, but this has not solved the issue. For me it looks like a bug in the Qt QML.

Is there any workaround for this issue?

Comment: Try to add to window `Component.onCompleted: { x = 0; y = 0; }`

Comment: @folibis Added but it has not fixed the issue. I have also tried creating a MouseArea and setting y to 0 on click, this does not help either.

Comment: set target: mainWindow on PropertyAnimation  and try it with constants for example set from: 0 to: 100.

Comment: @Angel.Risteski this code
    PropertyAnimation {
        target: mainWindow;
        property: "x";
        from: 0;
        to: 100;
    }
does not work at all - no animation happens.

Comment: @OlegLokshyn did you call start on animation on some trigger?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a workaround for the issue.

Setting on the root ApplicationWindow

```
flags: Qt.BypassWindowManagerHint
```

or

```
flags: Qt.X11BypassWindowManagerHint
```

solves the issue for me. Note that the issue was reproduced on Ubuntu 16.04, I have tried to reproduce it on Windows with no luck.

I would suggest using both flags:

```
flags: Qt.BypassWindowManagerHint | Qt.X11BypassWindowManagerHint
```

Here is a link to the flag`s documentation: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qt.html#WindowType-enum